# Check if Django Object in Many-to-Many Exists then Display Object Only

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I have a list of tools that have a part added as a bundle. The bundle is listed as a part in a many-to-many field, so I need to iterate over the parts to see if the add-on product exists for the tool being displayed. If the part exists, then I want to display just the part itself.  I've tried working it out with the code below and it does check if it exists, but prints out the queryset. I understand the `.all()` is the cause of this but I can't figure out how to check and then just display the single part.  Thank you for your help.

```
{% for p in tool.parts.all %}
  {% if 'bp-01' %}
    <h3>Bundle Included:</h3>
    {{ p.model_number }}
    ...
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

**Part Model**

```
class Part(Timestamp):
    model_number = models.ForeignKey(ModelNumber)
    price = models.SmallIntegerField()
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    slug = models.SlugField(help_text="slug-title-should-be-like-this")
    description = RichTextField()
    type = models.ForeignKey(Type, blank=True)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
```

**Tool Model**

```
class Tool(Timestamp):
    model_number = models.ForeignKey(ModelNumber)
    price = models.SmallIntegerField()
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    slug = models.SlugField(help_text="slug-title-should-be-like-this")
    description = RichTextField()
    type = models.ForeignKey(Type)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
    parts = models.ManyToManyField(Part, blank=True, related_name="parts")
```

**Model Number Model**

```
class ModelNumber(models.Model):
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100, unique=True, help_text="slug-title-should-be-like-this")

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Model Number'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Model Numbers'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.slug
```

Comment: Why do you have `{% if 'bp-01' %}`? It will always be True, because it's a non-empty string.

Comment: Because I am still a helpless noob, trying to figure things out :)

Comment: How does `bp-01` relate to product? Is it the expected value of a field?

Comment: I added my part and tool models for your review.  bp-01 is the model number of a part and is not included with every tool.

Comment: What does your ModelNumber model look like

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just have slug field on `ModelNumber` you can use `{% if p.model_number.slug== 'bp-01' %}` to check for the condition:

```
{% for p in tool.parts.all %}
  {% if p.model_number.slug == 'bp-01' %}
    <h3>Bundle Included:</h3>
    {{ p.model_number }}
    ...
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how your `ModelNumber` model looks, you can compare the values with something like this:

```
{% for p in tool.parts.all %}
  {% if p.model_number.number == 'bp-01' %}
    <h3>Bundle Included:</h3>
    {{ p.model_number }}
    ...
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

This is assuming that `ModelNumber` looks something like this:

```
class ModelNumber(models.Model):
    number = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    ....

    def __str__(self):
        return self.number
```

Comment: I added my ModelNumber model.  I set it as a SlugField since I was only going to use it to match parts to tools.  I am up for suggestions if this is not preferred.  Thank you.

Comment: If you just have `slug` field on `ModelNumber` you can use `{% if p.model_number.slug== 'bp-01' %}` to check for the condition.

Comment: @AKS that worked - can't believe it was so easy :).  Can you respond with a solution that I can accept as a correct answer? Hybrid - thank you for taking time to help.

Comment: @StudioRooster, Glad that it helped. I added my comment as an answer.